# gatsby can't fetch all graphql data on vercel production

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, vercel, nacelle

I am working on a Headless eCommerce website using [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/), [Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/). [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/) and [Nacelle](https://nacelle.com/).

It works fine if I run the app using `npm run dev`, I can see all graphql data from Contentful.

That's what I mean is that all of graphql data can be fetched on the local side even `npm run build`, but it doesn't compile all of graphql data on production.

Here are some of the logs while building the gatsby app on [Vercel](https://vercel.com/).

The logs say that there's no errors, but I can see some of warnings from there.

[image]

[image]

Here's the graphql query, it works fine on local environment.

```
const HomePage = ({ data }) => {
  console.log('slider in index page---', data);
  ...
}

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    homepageSlider: nacelleContent(type: { eq: "heroBanner" }, handle: { eq: "home-slider" }) {
      title
      remoteFields
      featuredMedia {
        remoteImage {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData(height: 2500, placeholder: TRACED_SVG)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    benefits: nacelleContent(type: { eq: "list" }, handle: { eq: "benefits" }) {
      handle
      title
      remoteFields
    }
    certificates: ...
    testimonial: ...
    satisfacts: ...
    collections: ...
  }
}
```

If I check the console log on vercel, it says all of the data has `null` except `collections`.

But all of the data exist if I check console log on local environment.

[image]

Why does this happen? It seems like a gatsby or vercel issue.

```
// package.json

...
"dependencies": {
    "@contentful/rich-text-from-markdown": "^15.0.0",
    "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer": "^15.0.0",
    "@contentful/rich-text-types": "^15.0.0",
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.35",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.14.1",
    "@nacelle/client-js-sdk": "^3.1.0",
    "@nacelle/gatsby-source-nacelle": "^2.10.2",
    "@nacelle/react-components": "^2.10.1",
    "@nacelle/react-dev-utils": "^2.10.1",
    "@nacelle/react-hooks": "^2.11.2",
    "@nacelle/react-recharge": "^2.11.0",
    "@react-hook/media-query": "^1.1.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "change-case": "^4.1.2",
    "fuse.js": "^6.4.1",
    "gatsby": "^2.27.0",
    "gatsby-alias-imports": "^1.0.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-emotion": "^4.5.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-fullstory": "^3.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager": "^3.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^1.1.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "^4.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^4.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-scroll-reveal": "0.0.7",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-transition-link": "^1.20.5",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.6.1",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.7.0",
    "gsap": "^3.6.1",
    "nuka-carousel": "^4.7.7",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "postcss": "^8.2.8",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-alice-carousel": "^2.5.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.8",
    "lint-staged": "^10.2.11",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.4"
  },
  ...
```

```
// gatsby-config.js

require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: '@nacelle/gatsby-source-nacelle',
      options: {
        nacelleSpaceId: process.env.GATSBY_NACELLE_SPACE_ID,
        nacelleGraphqlToken: process.env.GATSBY_NACELLE_GRAPHQL_TOKEN,
        cmsPreviewEnabled: process.env.NACELLE_PREVIEW_MODE,
        contentfulPreviewSpaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_PREVIEW_SPACE_ID,
        contentfulPreviewApiToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_PREVIEW_API_TOKEN,
        cacheDuration: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 // 1 day in ms
      }
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-postcss',
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        start_url: `/`,
        icon: `src/images/favicon-32.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      }
    },
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    'gatsby-plugin-image',
    'gatsby-plugin-emotion',
    'gatsby-alias-imports',
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager`,
      options: {
        id: process.env.GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID,
        includeInDevelopment: false,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-scroll-reveal`,
    // `gatsby-plugin-transition-link`
  ]
};
```

**UPDATE:**
Node v14.x is running on my local environment, and tried to select Node version 12 on the Vercel.

Many warning messages were disappeared, but I had no luck.

What I think that's weird is that I can see the content nodes difference between `develop` and `build`.

[image]
[image]

As you can see the images, it has created 128 content nodes while running `npm run dev` on the local side.

Otherwise, it has created only 100 content nodes on Vercel.

I am not sure if that is the main issue.

But basically gatsby has a rule of limitation for the content nodes?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this happen? It seems like a gatsby or vercel issue.

It's hard to say with the provided details. To me, it seems that the Vercel server is facing a timeout response for some GraphQL queries/products/nodes (the warnings) so it could be a pang of shared guilt.

To debug and try to fix the issue at the same time, taking into account that the project works perfectly fine locally, I would try to match environments, starting by setting the same Node version. This will assure you that you are running the same dependency version.

Vercel allows you to configure the Node version from the backoffice or by setting a `node` property inside `engine` object in the `package.json`. From the [docs](https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#official-runtimes/node-js/node-js-version):

> Defining the `node` property inside engines of a `package.json` file
> will override the selection made in the Project Settings and print a
> Build Step warning if the version does not match.
>
> In order to find out which Node.js version your Deployment is using,
> run `node -v` in the Build Command or log the output of
> `process.version`.

So add:

```
"engines": { "node": "12.x" }
```

Being `12.x` the prompted version when running the `node -v` command.

Hopefully, this will fix your issue but if not, it would help you to debug better.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for answering to my question. Chaning Node version didn't fix it, but I can see many warning messages were disappeared. Please check the `UPDATE:`.

Comment: Try to replicate Vercel locally with Serverless in localhost: https://vercel.com/blog/vercel-dev

Comment: Trying to replicate Vercel locally worked fine. But Vercel production does not work.

Comment: At first, I linked the current Vercel project and used `vercel env pull`. It created `.env` file and copied the variables. After that, I used `vercel dev`. I was able to see the same problem. It was getting only 100 content nodes.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas... Open a thread/discussion to the plugin repository or try playing with plugin's options

Comment: We need a minimal reproducible example, to be honest. Debugging with the information provided is almost impossible.